# What's so huge about Measurable Cardinals defined in this way??

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have been wrestling with trying to understand measurable cardinals for a couple of years now and am still having problems.  I am probably missing something very obvious and thus am a bit ashamed even to braoch the topic again.  But it bugs me enough that I will throw such caution to the wind and seek some help.

Here is a standard definition of a measurable cardinal,

"k, is [a set which has]a two-valued measure on a cardinal κ, or more generally, on any set. A cardinal,

κ, can be described as a subdivision of all of its subsets into large and small sets such that

κ itself is large

∅ and all singletons {α},α∈κ are small

Complements of small sets are large and vice versa

The intersection of fewer than κ large sets is again large​."

Now my first problem here is a small one, namely, that while I can see why the complements of small sets must be large, I don't see why the complements of large sets need to be small, since, for exmaple, the complement of the large set interval [0,1/3] in the unit interval I, is simply (1/3, 1], which is also large and has cardinality c.

So maybe I have already gone wrong somehow.  But please allow me to get to my  bigger problem.  As I understand [or MISunderstand] things, the separation of a set into such big and small classes of sets simply means that one has put an ultrafilter on the subsets of k.  One does this, I assume, because one is not particularly interested in subsets of measure 0, only those which have some finite measure that can contribute to the sum of the measures of all the included large subsets.  Now rather than try to do the impossible and actually figure out the measure of each large subset, one simply assigns a measure of 1 to each of them.  So far so good??

But, -- and this is the big sticking point for me that I can't seem to get beyond,-- all of the large sets to be summed up, and their unions and intersections too, are included in the Power Set of k, or P(k).  Thus it seems that either: 1.] k must have a cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of P(k), which I know is not the case, since in, say, R^2 the cardinality of the latter is merely 2^c, or 2.] k must be summing up something other than the measures of the large sets in the ultrafilter of k, but if THAT is the case, what exactly IS it summing up??

I suppose there might be another possibility, that 3.] putting an ultrafilter on the powerset of the Reals does not allow one to produce a measurable cardinal of any type, that one must start instead with a much larger set.  But that doesn't seem likely either since all of the original discussion of measurable cardinals by Ulam derives them from operations on standard Real intervals, almost as if he is thinking only about Lebesgue measures.

So then, what gives??

OK, now before I think better of the matter, I will post this, and brace myself for the consequences of making a complete ass of myself.  Anyway, thanks for reading, and should you wish to do so, responding to these two questions.

Comment: "k must have a cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of P(k), which I know is not the case" Um, every set *does* have cardinality less than or equal to that of its powerset.

Comment: "while I can see why the complements of small sets must be large, I don't see why the complements of large sets need to be small, since ..." It sounds like you're already interpreting "large" in a certain way. Some reasonable "largeness" notions - e.g. nonzero Lebesgue measure - don't have this property. You can forget the word "large" completely in the definition of "measurable cardinal" (and perhaps should, at least at first): $\kappa$ is measurable iff there is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$.

Comment: A better measure-theoretic analogue here is *full measure* - the complement of a full-measure set is null, the union of countably many null sets is null, etc. Of course the set of full-measure sets fails to be an ultrafilter since there are plenty of sets which are neither null nor full, but I think it's still a better starting point then thinking about positive measure. (I'm posting these as comments since I'm not sure I understand yet exactly the point at issue; once I have a better sense of that, I'll post an actual answer.)

Comment: Noah Schweber, #1; Yes, of course every set has a cardinaliy less than its Power Set.  I am simply saying that my problem is that since we know that the whole Ultrafilter is composed only of subsets of the Power Set of k, its cardinality must be less than or equal to the cardinality of that Power Set, which in the case at hand is only 2^c, hardly a "large cardinal."

Comment: What is "the case at hand"? The continuum $c$ is **not** a measurable cardinal (or above a measurable cardinal) at all. I think you may have some incorrect underlying assumptions here.

Comment: Noah Schweber #2: I am using the word "large" only because that it the term giving in the Wikipedia definition.  I have also seen that definition several other places. If we use your alternative formulation that "k is measurable iff there is a k-complete ultrafilter on k," which may well be better, how can we know if there is such a thing or not until we find some way to define such an ultrafilter and apply it to k?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're asking. (1) It sounds like you think "large" is a technical term here; it's not, it's just meant as informal motivation. My "alternative formulation" is *exactly the same* definition, I've just removed the I-think-in-this-case-confusing "flavor." (2) I still don't understand how $\mathbb{R}$ is relevant to any of this. (3) "how can we know if there is such a thing or not until we find some way to define such an ultrafilter and apply it to k?" I don't know what you're asking here. Are you asking whether we can prove that a specific cardinal is measurable?

Comment: Noah Schweber #3: Since I am doing my research in conjunction with reading Ulam's famous paper of 1930, which indicates the possibility of a measurable cardinal without defining it, I was assuming that he is there using a concept of Lebesque measure, since many other works of that period utilize that notion from the developing Analysis of the day.  It is possible that he means Baire measure, but I doubt it, and that wouldn't solve the problem I'm having. However the subsets are measured, don't they have to sum up to k, and do so 1+1+1 .... k times? What ARE these subsets anyway? How disjoint?

Comment: Noah Schweber #4:  I am not assuming either that c is measurable or that there is any uncountable measurble that is not much, much larger than both c and 2^c.

Comment: Re: your second comment, then why did $\mathbb{R}$ enter into your post at all? Re: your first comment, *neither* Lebesgue nor Baire measure are relevant here: the definition of a measurable cardinal is **entirely self-contained** and should be understood on its own terms, forcing a connection with analysis at this point is simply unhelpful. "What ARE these subsets anyway? How disjoint?" What do you mean "what sets"? There's just too much unclear here, and it seems to center around bringing analysis into this. It would be good to back up a bit: are you comfortable with ultrafilters in general?

Comment: Noah Scweber #5: No, I don't think "large" is a technical term, although when Ulam uses the term I assume he means an uncountable , not countable, subset of the Ultrafilter.  He also speaks of intervals on the Real line and says that the subsets involved are "disjoint" from one another wich suggests they are all small copies of the Real line with cardinality c.  It is possible he means something else, I suppose, but wouldn't he then say so?

Comment: "I don't think "large" is a technical term, although when Ulam uses the term I assume he means an uncountable , not countable, subset of the Ultrafilter" It seems that you are conflating subsets of the cardinal with subsets of the ultrafilter (or that might have been a typo). And again, $\mathbb{R}$ is simply not relevant here (although analytic considerations did lead to the idea in the first place); to reiterate, you're mixing two fundamentally different things.

Comment: Noah Schweber, #6: As to "Are you asking whether we can prove that a specific cardinal is measurable?" I am more interested in knowlng how to construct one from sets I know about, and that Ulam knew about in 1930, but yes, I think it should also be possible to determine whether any cardinal one encounters is measurable or not.

Comment: "I am more interested in knowlng how to construct one from sets I know about, and that Ulam knew about in 1930" It's consistent with ZFC that no measurable cardinals exist at all. Indeed, they're so huge that there's no good way to build them using stuff known at the time (the way we tend to get them is via elementary embeddings of the universe into inner models). For that matter, how would you "construct" an *inaccessible* cardinal?

Comment: "I think it should also be possible to determine whether any cardinal one encounters is measurable or not." I don't know any sense in which that's true. However, and in the same line as my previous comment, certainly every cardinal you can easily define can be proved to be non-measurable: e.g. $2^{\aleph_0}$, the first $\aleph$-fixed point, the first inaccessible (if inaccessibles exist in the first place), the first Mahlo (if Mahlos exist in the first place), the first weakly compact (if w.c.s exist in the first place), etc.

Comment: Noah Scweber, #7: I am sorry if all of my questions and comments have merely confused you, but I can only articulate things as well as I currently understand them.  But I do greatly appreciate your responding to my queries about this, to me anyway, mysterious matter, and hope that I have not alienated you too much with my inability to be more precise in explaining the problem I am having with the ultrafilter and k-additive definition of measurable cardinals.  Thanks so much for your replies!

Comment: (You're not alienating me at all, don't worry.) "the problem I am having with the ultrafilter and k-additive definition of measurable cardinals" What other definition are you looking at? (There's a definition in terms of elementary embeddings but - although it tends to be far more useful, actually - I'd stay away from it for now. And these are really the only two definitions I know.)

Comment: I've added an answer which might help; let me know if there's some point it doesn't address.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that things are getting confused by bringing $\mathbb{R}$ and Lebesgue measure into this. Measurable cardinals should be understood on their own terms. Of course historically the idea of measurable cardinals was motivated by analytic considerations, but I think this is a situation where following the history is actually less helpful than just looking at the modern treatment. In particular, **I would not look at the original papers to learn this stuff**.

---

A cardinal $\kappa$ is measurable iff there is a (non-principal) $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. That is, iff there is a family $\mathbb{U}$ of subsets of $\kappa$ such that:

1. $\kappa\in\mathbb{U}$ and no finite subset of $\kappa$ is in $\mathbb{U}$.
2. If $A\in\mathbb{U}$ and $B\supseteq A$ then $B\in\mathbb{U}$.
3. If $A,B\in\mathbb{U}$ then $A\cap B\in\mathbb{U}$.
4. If $A\subseteq\kappa$ then either $A\in\mathbb{U}$ or $\kappa\setminus A\in\mathbb{U}$.
5. If $I$ is a set of cardinality $<\kappa$ and $A_i\not\in\mathbb{U}$ for each $i\in I$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\not\in\mathbb{U}$.

The first three points say that $\mathbb{U}$ is a nonprincipal filter on $\kappa$; the fourth point says that $\mathbb{U}$ is an ultrafilter; the final point says that $\mathbb{U}$ is $\kappa$-complete (that the union of fewer-than-$\kappa$ sets not in $\mathbb{U}$ is still not in $\mathbb{U}$).

Note that in the last point, the thing which is of size $<\kappa$ is the **set-of-sets** $\{A_i: i\in I\}$; the $A_i$s themselves can be of size $\kappa$ or not.

- It is true, however, and a good exercise to prove, that if $\mathbb{U}$ satisfies (1)-(5) we'll always have $B\not\in\mathbb{U}$ if $\vert B\vert<\kappa$. Think of this as a strengthening of (the second part of) (1). (Some expositions even build this directly into the definition.)

---

You can also think of such a $\mathbb{U}$ as a map from $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ to $\{0,1\}$ *(and I think this is the context behind your comment "What ARE these subsets anyway? How disjoint?")*. The appropriate definition now is just the same (1)-(5) above but with "$-\in\mathbb{U}$" and "$-\not\in\mathbb{U}$" replaced with "$\mathbb{U}(-)=1$" and "$\mathbb{U}(-)=0$" respectively; and then $\kappa$ is measurable iff a *function* $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ (not $[0,1]$ incidentally) exists satisfying the appropriately-translated versions of (1)-(5). **I would consider this the same definition of measurability, just rephrased a bit**, but you may find it meaningfully more or less clear.

Condition (5) - appropriately translated to the function context - then becomes a kind of weak additivity condition: it says that (for $I$ a set of size $<\kappa$ and $A_i\subseteq\kappa$ for each $i\in I$) $$\mathbb{U}(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)=\max\{\mathbb{U}(A_i): i\in I\}.$$ Note that $(i)$ we're using $\max$ instead of $\sum$ here and $(ii)$ the $A_i$s can be any subsets of $\kappa$ whatsoever (and in particular no disjointness is assumed).

**We can rephrase condition (5) as a genuine additivity property**, but then we have to introduce disjointness: if we want to replace $\max$ with $\sum$ we need to require that the $A_i$s are disjoint.

Of course $\kappa$ itself is the union of $\kappa$-many sets on which $\mathbb{U}$ is zero (namely, all the singletons); this is why we only have completeness for sets-of-sets of size $<\kappa$. It is, however, worth noting that by conditions (1) and (3) in the definition we have that **there are no disjoint sets in $\mathbb{U}$**: if $A,B\in\mathbb{U}$ then $A\cap B\in\mathbb{U}$, and $\emptyset\not\in \mathbb{U}$ since $\emptyset$ is finite.

---

I think that at this point it's good to turn to a specific exercise, which I suspect will help clear things up a bit:

> Show that every measurable cardinal is regular.

Comment: +1 I"m glad you emphasized not trying to learn this from the original papers. At various times, some authors have used  "measurable cardinal" to mean what we now call "cardinal $\geq$ some measurable cardinal" (i.e., czarrying a countably complete 2-valued measure), and other authors have used it to mean what we now call "real-valued measurable cardinal". It's not too hard to sort all this out, but only after one has learned the relevant concepts.

Comment: I am still attempting to wrap my head around your latest comment, Noah, but I've been very busy lately so I will need to think a while longer and then get back to you.  Things do seem to be getting clearer the more I wrestle with the problem, but I will need more time to answer more intelligently ..... like perhaps infinite time of at least Aleph omega.