# Is there a family of humongous sets?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, cardinals

I'm once again trying to define a meaningful notion of size for sets.

Let $R$ be a set of size $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$ and say $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal P(R)$ is a *family of humongous sets* if it has the two following properties:

- If $P = \{P_n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a countable partition of $R$, then $P\cap\mathcal F\ne\varnothing$, i.e., there is an humongous set in $P$.
- If $\{H_n: n\in\mathbb N\}\subset\mathcal F$ is a countable family of humongous sets, then $\left|\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} H_n\right| = \mathfrak c$.

Now I wonder, of course, if one can find a family of humongous sets.

---

While wondering I noticed the chosen cardinals are not really doing anything for the definition, so let's generalize it!

Let $S$ be a set, $\alpha$ a cardinal and say $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal P(S)$ is a *family of $\alpha-$humongous sets* if it has the two following propeties:

- If $P=\{P_\kappa: \kappa<\alpha\}$ is a partition of $S$, then $P\cap \mathcal F\ne\varnothing$.
- If $\{H_\kappa: \kappa<\alpha\}\subset\mathcal F$, then $\displaystyle\left|\bigcap_{\kappa<\alpha} H_\kappa\right| = |S|$.

If the answear to my first question is false, one could ask if there is some size for $S$ so that it admits a family of $\aleph_0-$humongous sets and, if there is, what is the smallest such size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least taking $\vert S\vert=\alpha$ you're basically looking for the notion of a **measurable cardinal**: $\kappa$ is measurable iff its powerset admits a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ satisfying your conditions which is also closed upwards (which doesn't add much to what you've got - in particular, the upwards closure of any family satisfying your properties still satisfies your properties).

*Actually, since you're mainly interested in the $\alpha=\aleph_0$ case, you're really looking for **Ulam measurable** cardinals. But the smallest Ulam measurable, if it exists, is also the smallest measurable, so at the level of "How big are such things?" the notions are no different.*

Here's a proof that your first question has a negative answer. Without loss of generality, assume $R$ is the set of real numbers and suppose $\mathcal{F}$ had the desired properties. By your first bulletpoint there is some integer $z$ such that $[z,z+1)\in\mathcal{F}$; consider the partition of $R$ into intervals of this form.

Now refine this partition by replacing the single block $[z,z+1)$ with two blocks $[z, z+{1\over 2})$ and $[z+{1\over 2}, z+1)$. By points 1 and 2, one of these two pieces must be in $\mathcal{F}$. Iterating this strategy, we can find a sequence of intervals each of which is in $\mathcal{F}$ but such that the diameter of the $n$th interval is $2^{-n}$. Now apply your second bulletpoint to this sequence. The intersection of these intervals has at most one element, so we get a contradiction.

It is not immediate that measurable cardinals must be particularly big, but in fact this is the case; indeed, the usual axioms of set theory cannot prove that measurable cardinals exist, and the smallest measurable cardinal (if it exists) is truly gigantic. See e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432758/gauging-the-size-of-measurable-cardinals-and-inaccessible-cardinals/1432785#1432785), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251789/whats-so-huge-about-measurable-cardinals-defined-in-this-way/3252020#3252020), although these posts are necessarily a bit technical.

Comment: That was unexpected. Before I lose all of my hopes, what if we change the partition in the first bulletpoint for a family $P_0\subset P_1\subset P_2\subset\dots$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\omega} P_n = R$? Is there still no humongous family of sets over $R$?